How does the parametric implementation of the double dabble algorithm work?
Shift and add 3 is a high quality algorithm for converting binary quantities into BCD quantities, very simple but very cleaver, here are the general steps (I am omitting the column arrange preamble):

Shift the binary number left one bit.
If 8 shifts have taken place, the BCD number is in the Hundreds, Tens, and Units column.
If the binary value in any of the BCD columns is 5 or greater, add 3 to that value in that BCD column.
Go to 1.

A run of the algorithm is showed below (taken from bin_to_bcd):

Now, I was trying to find a way to implement this algorithm in a parametric way in Verilog, but gladly, somebody already did, as shown below:
// parametric Verilog implementation of the double dabble binary to BCD converter
// for the complete project, see
// https://github.com/AmeerAbdelhadi/Binary-to-BCD-Converter

module bin2bcd
 #( parameter                W = 18)  // input width
  ( input      [W-1      :0] bin   ,  // binary
    output reg [W+(W-4)/3:0] bcd   ); // bcd {...,thousands,hundreds,tens,ones}

  integer i,j;

  always @(bin) begin
    for(i = 0; i <= W+(W-4)/3; i = i+1) bcd[i] = 0;     // initialize with zeros
    bcd[W-1:0] = bin;                                   // initialize with input vector
    for(i = 0; i <= W-4; i = i+1)                       // iterate on structure depth
      for(j = 0; j <= i/3; j = j+1)                     // iterate on structure width
        if (bcd[W-i+4*j -: 4] > 4)                      // if > 4
          bcd[W-i+4*j -: 4] = bcd[W-i+4*j -: 4] + 4'd3; // add 3
  end

endmodule

This algorithm works, problem is... I don't know how!. There are many questions I have, but I'll ask the two that are bogging me most:

There is no shift operation anywhere, why?
Every reference will tell you that the addition of the 3 constant is done when the value is bigger than 5, so, why is comparing to 4 instead?

Any insight will be very much appreciated, and I've contacted the author already, no answer yet.
Regards

Q2 because if it is >4 it must be 5 or greater!

Have a look at the Wikipedia page for this algorithm there is a diagram there which illustrates what this implementation is doing.

You should first read the Wiki page on double-dabble. But if you want to see it in action, here's a picture of converting a 24-bit binary value into 8 decimal digits (up to 16,777,215):

Each yellow block is one double-dabble module. And you can pretty much see how it works from this above example.
By the way, if you figure out how to write a generic algorithm in Verilog to accept a binary width as a parameter and to correctly and automatically generate an output such as the above, I'd love to see it. I've tried. And failed. Fixed sizes are easy. But at least for me, a generic way to instance the above as one of many possible outcomes has left me wondering. And I've posted elsewhere (Xilinx board) to see if anyone there can help. None such, so far.
Just for more fun, read the following two algorithms that convert between octal and decimal that I posted up here. Working out why they work is also fun.

my bad :( I thought that double dabble and shift and add 3 was the same algorithm

the code posted works and is parametric, try it! And if you understand its ins and outs, post an explanation :P

@JacobMoralesGonzalez Better, you post it. It must perform pruning. For example, 81 modules for 24-bits input. (Though 5 of those can be further pruned.) There's a by-3 per tree-branch. But the last few don't follow the by-3 rule. For example, see 21, 18, 15, 12, 9 (which follow the by-3) then 5 and 1, which do not follow it.

The algorithm is scanning 4 columns at a time. bcd[W-i+4*j -: 4] is an indexed part select looking at just 4 columns at a time. Each iteration is looking a shifting window of 4 bits.
And "5 or greater" is the same as "greater than 4".

Thanks @dave_59, as always.
